# Angular. Create directive redirecting model to given attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to create directive 'myDrc', which makes the input-field

```
<input my-drc ng-model='item.value' my-attr='item.shadow'>
```

to redirect an input-value into 'item.shadow' and to set 'item.value' to be F(item.shadow) where F is some function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't even need your own directive for this, since there is already a `ng-change` which calls a function when the input is changed. Therefor you just need to write your logic in the controller:

```
$scope.Shadow = function(input) {
    $scope.data.shadow = input;
    if (input === "cheat") {
        $scope.data.input = "YOU FOUND THE CODE!";
    }
};
```

and call it like this:

```
<input ng-model="data.input" ng-change="Shadow(data.input)" >
```

if you type in "cheat" then the input text is replaced. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mt7k/).

EDIT: Update to address comment.

No problem, you can either just set it up as a directive controller that you throw on the input, or you can do it like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Mt7k/2/):

```
    link: function(scope) {
        scope.ShadowFunc = function() {
            scope.shadow = scope.ngModel;
            if (scope.ngModel === "cheat") {
                scope.ngModel = "YOU FOUND THE CODE!";
            }
        };
    }
```

and then you just need to pass in the data correctly:

```
<test-dir model="data.input" shadow="data.shadow">
</test-dir>

    scope: {
        model: '=',
        shadow: '='
    },
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for ngChange example, but I'm trying to find or construct reusable directive doing exactly what is in the question (b/c it's only small part of what I expect to do), so one-time hardcoded controller is not the goal.

Comment: Wow, thanks. You've helped me a lot. Finally I've got how it works.

Comment: Awesome, happy coding! Also in the future it would be great if you could post some things that you've tried, so us answerers could have a better idea where to go.